# Windows display settings is causing Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width to be incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We have made a terms of use application that fills the user's entire screen, and centres the text in the middle of the screen.

We have achieved these by setting the Location to `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X + 10` and then the width to `Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 10,` - this gives effectively 10px padding and otherwise perfectly central text.

The problem however, is when users change the 'Make it easier to read what's on your screen' option to 125%, the Bounds.Width value is incorrect, and the text goes way off the screen.

[image: Make it easier to read what's on your screen, set to 125%]

Interestingly if you set it to 'Larger - 150%' it calculates the screen width just fine.

I've tried using `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width` too, but that just gives the same (incorrect) result.

Is there anyway of resolving this please? Thank you

(edit) Here is the full code which generates the element:

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e) {
    this._webBrowser = new WebBrowser {
      IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false,
      AllowWebBrowserDrop = false,
      Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X + 10, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y + 150),
      Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 20,
      ScrollBarsEnabled = true,
      DocumentText = "<html><body><div>" + agreement.Terms + "</div></body></html>"
    };
}
```

Comment: That's not it, dpiAware doesn't kick in until you go *past* 125%.

Answer (score 3):

Sight unseen (always post a code snippet), this happened because you put the code in the wrong place.  You are setting the size in the constructor of your Form class.  Then, since the form was originally designed at 96 DPI, your form gets auto-scaled to accommodate the larger DPI setting.  Which *grows* the form by 125%, now making it too big.

You must set the size *after* the form is rescaled.  The Load event handler is the best opportunity, in fact one of the few reasons to actually need Load.  At that point, the scaling is already applied but the window not yet visible.  Therefore the best place to override Size and Location properties.  Fix:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        var scr = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
        this.Bounds = new Rectangle(
            scr.WorkingArea.Left + 10, scr.WorkingArea.Top,
            scr.WorkingArea.Width - 20, scr.WorkingArea.Bottom);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

---

After edit, you should *not* use screen coordinates to set the control's Location and Size property.  A child control's location is relative from it's Parent's client area and must fit inside it.  Fix:

```
this._webBrowser = new WebBrowser {
    Location = new Point(10, 10),
    Width = this.ClientSize.Width - 20,
    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top,
    // etc...
};
```

Setting the Anchor ensures it resizes along with the parent, probably what you want.  This code belongs in the constructor, not OnLoad() since now you **do** want the browser to get rescaled along with the form.  If you had used the designer then you'd automatically would have gotten the correct code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I've just updated the original post with the code - it is actually already running in the OnLoad function :(

Comment: It makes no sense to set a child control's Location and Size based on screen coordinates.   You must set the form's properties, as shown in my snippet.  The WebBrowser goes along for the ride.  Set its Anchor properties to make it resize along with the form, turn on the Right and Bottom anchors.

Comment: Thank you so much - I'm sorry of this is a stupid question, but I've tried setting both the width and height to this.ClientSize.Width/Height respectively, but it's only around 300 pixels wide and 600 high? Is there anyway to make it 100% using the anchors? Thanks again